# Question about: できないことなどない

Tags: translation

A powerful man who is pursuing Tomoko has helped her brother who thanks him profusely.  He says:

> 知子の頼みだ。私に、できないことなどない

My translation:

> 知子の頼みだ

It was at Tomoko’s request.

> 私に、できないことなどない

?

How do you translate the last sentence? Is it:

There is nothing I cannot do (like it is boastful)

or

There is nothing I would not do (for Tomoko)

or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sentence literally means "There is nothing I cannot do (for Tomoko)."

In this context, of course he basically wants to say "I want to do anything for Tomoko," and not "I am omnipotent like God." Still, the sentence is a bit exaggerated, and only very proud and powerful men would say something like this.

Comment: Thank you for that because the context doesn't make it clear if he was being generous or boastful. What you described it as very much fits into his character.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you basically got it:

> できないことなどない.
>   There isn't really anything I can't do.

I added "really" to convey the idea there from など.

Comment: So, it is a bit boastful? Like he is trying to show off his power?

Comment: @Noob i don't know. without more context it's hard to say. it could just as easily be generosity. but then again context will help determine that.